# Multi-threading problems on Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework as my way of communicating with the database and fetching/writing information on it, on a ASP.NET CORE application. (Used as a very basic API, acting as a server for a separate application.)

There comes a time when the clients make requests to join a given lobby. I've just confirmed that if 4 requests at the same time enter, they will all be signed up on the lobby, but the player count did not update, and if it did - it'd go over the top/limit.

Am I using entity framework wrong? Is there an alternative tool to be used for such things, or should I just make it so it uses a single thread (If someone can remind me how), or encapsulate all my actions/endpoints with a lock block statement?

No matter how I structure my code, it's all prone to these same-timed http requests, moving parallelly through my repository/context.

It'd be great if I could make some kind of a queue, which I believe is what encapsulating everything in a lock would do.

EDIT:

As answered by [vasily.sib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2716623/vasily-sib), I can resolve this with the use of concurrency tokens. Please check his comment for some amazing information on how to use them!

Comment: Can you share you code snippet?

Comment: _"Am I using entity framework wrong?"_ - wait a minute, I will use my telepathic super power... Yes, I see now. You using it wrong.

Comment: Different DbContext instances will be instantiated for every request, and different DbContext instances should work from different threads just fine.

Comment: now seriously: look [what I have found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency) (and [another useful link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency)) just after 0.37 seconds of googling for _"ef core concurrency"_. What you actualy looking for is an optimistic concurrency control.

Comment: @vasily.sib I'll try that just now, I think this might be the nail on my overhead!

Comment: BTW, this looks like realtime app. Have you looked at [ASP.Net Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @vasily.sib I'll have to check it out! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that operations like these...

```
_context.Sessions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == sessionId).PlayerCount += 1;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

...are not atomic. With `FirstOrDefault` you get the session (which you dereference then without a `null` check, so `First` would be a better option here, since you will get a better error message). Then you save the changes in another step. Between those steps another concurrent thread could have changed and already saved a new value for `PlayerCount`.

There are multiple ways to resolve this, and most of them would require some changes on DB level.

One way to resolve it is to write a stored procedure that can do the update atomically. You would need an `UPDATE` statement similar to this one:

```
UPDATE Sessions
SET PlayerCount = PlayerCount + 1
FROM Sessions
WHERE Id = @SessionId
```

If you don't want to use stored procedures you could send this SQL directly to the DB.

One problem with this solution is that later you also do this step:

```
if (thisSession.Size == thisSession.PlayerCount)
{
    thisSession.Status = SessionStatus.Active;
    _context.SaveChanges(); // this can be trimmed and added at the previous scope
}
```

You would have to integrate this in your `UPDATE` statement to keep the operation atomic. If you want to add additional steps, things can get complicated.

Another way is to use optimistic concurrency built into EF core. In a nutshell, this means that when you save the data ef will first check whether the destination row is still in the same version compared to the moment you retrieved it.

To achieve that, your session needs a column that will contain a version counter. For SQL Server this would be a colun of type `rowversion`. Once you have this column, EF can do its optimistic concurrency magic. EF will throw a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` which you would have to handle. There are different ways to resolve the error. One easy way would be to repeat your entire operation until it works out.

Comment: Do I add a property in my entity model for the rowversion, or how exactly do I implement it in EF core? I'm using so far [Concurrency] restrictions on all my properties.

Comment: If using [ConcurrencyCheck] works for you, that's fine. Otherwise you will need to define one column of type `rowversion` which EF will automatically use for concurrency.